# Updating prod postgresql db with Flask Heroku

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, database-migration, heroku-postgres

I have ran the following command in my dev db:

```
flask db migrate -m "updated the schema" 
flask db upgrade
```

Which successfully did the migration and updated the schema. However, when I pushed the commit to heroku the prod schema didn't change. How can I do the same update in heroku prod postgresql?

I tried switching my profile code from:

```
web: gunicorn run:app --log-file=-
```

to:

```
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn run:app --log-file=-
```

& even adding:

```
heroku config:set FLASK_APP=run.py
```

for restarting. However, the prod db schema remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands did the job:

```
Heroku run bash
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```